# solving differential equations with parameters varying over intervals

Tags: r, parameters, differential-equations

I would like to solve a system of differential equations with parameters varying over intervlas.

Here is my code:

```
# LOADING PACKAGES
  library(deSolve)

#  DATA CREATION 
t1 <- data.frame(times=seq(from=0,to=5,by=0.1),interval=c(rep(0,10),rep(1,20),rep(2,21)))
length(t1[which(t1$times<1),])             #10
length(t1[which(t1$times>=1&t1$times<3),]) #20
length(t1[which(t1$times>=3),])            #21

t1$mueDP=c(rep(3.1,10),rep(2.6,20),rep(1.1,21))
t1$mueHD=c(rep(2.6,10),rep(1.7,20),rep(1.3,21))
t1$mueTX=c(rep(1.9,10),rep(3.3,20),rep(1.3,21))
t1$tau12=c(rep(5.5,10),rep(2.7,20),rep(0.7,21))
t1$tau13=c(rep(3.5,10),rep(1.3,20),rep(2.3,21))
t1$tau21=c(rep(4,10),rep(1.8,20),rep(2.8,21))
t1$tau23=c(rep(2.1,10),rep(2.1,20),rep(1.1,21))
t1$tau31=c(rep(3.9,10),rep(3.6,20),rep(1.6,21))
t1$tau32=c(rep(5.1,10),rep(1.4,20),rep(0.4,21))

t1

# FUNCTION SOLVING THE SYSTEM
rigidode <- function(times, y, parms) {
with(as.list(y), {
dert.comp_dp=-(tau12)*comp_dp+(tau21)*comp_hd-(tau13)*comp_dp+(tau31)*comp_tx-(mueDP)*comp_dp
dert.comp_hd=-(tau21)*comp_hd+(tau12)*comp_dp-(tau23)*comp_hd+(tau32)*comp_tx-(mueHD)*comp_hd
dert.comp_tx=-(tau31)*comp_tx+(tau13)*comp_dp-(tau32)*comp_tx+(tau23)*comp_hd-(mueTX)*comp_tx
dert.comp_dc=(mueDP)*comp_dp+(mueHD)*comp_hd+(mueTX)*comp_tx
list(c(dert.comp_dp, dert.comp_hd, dert.comp_tx, dert.comp_dc))
})
}


times <- t1$times

mueDP=t1$mueDP
mueHD=t1$mueHD
mueTX=t1$mueTX
mu_attendu=t1$mu_attendu
tau12=t1$tau12
tau13=t1$tau13
tau21=t1$tau21
tau23=t1$tau23
tau31=t1$tau31
tau32=t1$tau32
parms <- c("mueDP","mueHD","mueTX","mu_attendu","tau12","tau13","tau21","tau23","tau31","tau32")
yini <- c(comp_dp = 30, comp_hd = 60,comp_tx = 10, comp_dc = 0)

out_lsoda <- lsoda (times = times, y = yini, func = rigidode, parms = parms, rtol = 1e-9, atol = 1e-9)
out_lsoda
```

The problem is that the function rigidode is working only for constant parameters. I can't figure out how to vary my parameters over interval (from 0 to 2).

thanks

Comment: You should solve it piecewise, jumps in the ODE function play havoc with adaptive step size algorithms like `lsoda`. Thus solve from start to first jump point, change the constants, take the last state as the initial state and solve from first to second jump point etc.

Comment: I understand what you mean but can you give me an exemple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mily comment: Yes, it is possible with `t1`, here the solution:

Define `t1` (Intervall is not needed in my point of view).

```
t1 <- data.frame(times=seq(from=0, to=5, by=0.1))
t1$mueDP=c(rep(3.1,10),rep(2.6,20),rep(1.1,21))
t1$mueHD=c(rep(2.6,10),rep(1.7,20),rep(1.3,21))
t1$mueTX=c(rep(1.9,10),rep(3.3,20),rep(1.3,21))
t1$tau12=c(rep(5.5,10),rep(2.7,20),rep(0.7,21))
t1$tau13=c(rep(3.5,10),rep(1.3,20),rep(2.3,21))
t1$tau21=c(rep(4,10),rep(1.8,20),rep(2.8,21))
t1$tau23=c(rep(2.1,10),rep(2.1,20),rep(1.1,21))
t1$tau31=c(rep(3.9,10),rep(3.6,20),rep(1.6,21))
t1$tau32=c(rep(5.1,10),rep(1.4,20),rep(0.4,21))
```

Define the ODE function:

```
rigidode <- function(times, y, parms,t1) {

  ## find out in which line of t1 `times` is
  id <- min(which(times < t1$times))-1
  parms <- t1[id,-1]

  with(as.list(c(parms,y)), {

    dert.comp_dp <- -(tau12)*comp_dp+(tau21)*comp_hd-(tau13)*comp_dp+(tau31)*comp_tx-(mueDP)*comp_dp
    dert.comp_hd <- -(tau21)*comp_hd+(tau12)*comp_dp-(tau23)*comp_hd+(tau32)*comp_tx-(mueHD)*comp_hd
    dert.comp_tx <- -(tau31)*comp_tx+(tau13)*comp_dp-(tau32)*comp_tx+(tau23)*comp_hd-(mueTX)*comp_tx
    dert.comp_dc <- (mueDP)*comp_dp+(mueHD)*comp_hd+(mueTX)*comp_tx

    return(list(c(dert.comp_dp, dert.comp_hd, dert.comp_tx, dert.comp_dc)))
  })
}


times <- seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 0.1)


yini <- c(comp_dp = 30, comp_hd = 60, comp_tx = 10, comp_dc = 0)

parms <- t1[1,-1]

out_lsoda <- lsoda(times = times, y = yini, func = rigidode, parms = parms, rtol = 1e-9, atol = 1e-9, t1 = t1)
out_lsoda
```

Note that in the function call `lsoda` the argument `t1 = t1` is committed to the ODE function.

Answer (score 1):

Here the (in my meaning) best solution and some explanatory notes:

1. To make parameters available in the function, just use the `with(as.list(...))` function.

I made it easy and made a distinction of cases in the function:

```
rigidode <- function(times, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(parms,y)), {

    if(times > 1.1 & times < 3.1){      
      mueDP <- 2.6
      mueHD <- 1.7 
      mueTX <- 3.3  
      tau12 <- 2.7 
      tau13 <- 1.3
      tau21 <- 1.8 
      tau23 <- 2.1  
      tau31 <- 3.6 
      tau32 <- 1.4      
    }

    if(times > 3.1){      
      mueDP <- 1.1
      mueHD <- 1.3 
      mueTX <- 1.3  
      tau12 <- 0.7 
      tau13 <- 2.3
      tau21 <- 2.8 
      tau23 <- 1.1  
      tau31 <- 1.6 
      tau32 <- 0.4      
    }

    #un-comment the line below, if you want to see, if this works as expected
    # print(c(times, mueDP, mueHD, mueTX, tau12, tau13, tau21,tau23,tau31, tau23))

    dert.comp_dp <- -(tau12)*comp_dp+(tau21)*comp_hd-(tau13)*comp_dp+(tau31)*comp_tx-(mueDP)*comp_dp
    dert.comp_hd <- -(tau21)*comp_hd+(tau12)*comp_dp-(tau23)*comp_hd+(tau32)*comp_tx-(mueHD)*comp_hd
    dert.comp_tx <- -(tau31)*comp_tx+(tau13)*comp_dp-(tau32)*comp_tx+(tau23)*comp_hd-(mueTX)*comp_tx
    dert.comp_dc <- (mueDP)*comp_dp+(mueHD)*comp_hd+(mueTX)*comp_tx

    return(list(c(dert.comp_dp, dert.comp_hd, dert.comp_tx, dert.comp_dc)))
  })
}
```

The rest of the code is standard, just note, that the `parms` have the values of the times = 0.

```
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 0.1)

yini <- c(comp_dp = 30, comp_hd = 60, comp_tx = 10, comp_dc = 0)
parms <- c(mueDP = 3.1, mueHD = 2.6, mueTX = 1.9,  tau12 = 5.5, tau13 = 3.5,
       tau21 = 4.0, tau23 = 2.1,  tau31 = 3.9, tau32 = 5.1)

out_lsoda <- lsoda (times = times, y = yini, func = rigidode, parms = parms, rtol = 1e-9, atol = 1e-9)
out_lsoda
```

So in the end, I come to this solution. Please check if all the values I wrote are right, I just made your code work!

[image]

Comment: Thank you J_F for your answer!

Comment: Hi J_F, is it possible to solve this problem by using the data.frame called t1? I am asking you this because I want to do the resolution of the system using a data. In your example, you changes parameters over time with the condition if. Is it possible to do this otherwise?